# String concatenation with operator + vs using stringbuffer?

Tags: java, string

Is there any difference b/w 1 and 2 in terms of concatenation if i do it instance method. I mean in either case only one object will be constructed ultimately i.e "abc" .Yes only difference i see is  test will lie inside permgen space even thread come out of instance method but x will be garbage collected once thread is out of method but in terms of number of objects constructred will be same. Right?

```
// option 1
String test="a"+"b"+"c";

// option 2  
StringBuffer x = new StringBuffer().append("a").append("b").append("c").toString()
```

I referred the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html to reach this conclusion.

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First notice that the documentation you have linked is very old. Notice it's for **Java 1.4.2**.

> J2SE 1.4.2 is in its Java Technology End of Life (EOL) transition period. The EOL transition period began Dec, 11 2006 and will complete October 30th, 2008, when J2SE 1.4.2 will have reached its End of Service Life (EOSL).

In [newer versions of the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) this statement has been removed. However another statement has been added that you should be aware of:

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. **The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one**, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

---

Secondly notice that the documentation you refer to has this code:

```
x = "a" + 4 + "c";
```

The `4` there isn't just a typo. Your example is different because the compiler will convert the code to use just a single string literal. These two lines are the same:

```
x = "a" + "b" + "c"; 
x = "abc";
```

The string literal will be interned.

---

But in the general case where the compiler cannot just use a single string literal, the compiler will transform the first version into the second, except it will use `StringBuilder` instead because it is more efficient.

Comment: *"The compiler will transform the first version into the second"* I don't think it is the case.

Comment: But only in such simple scenario, right? If you have some logic between compiler will just keep doing "+" operator.

Comment: Well yeah, in this simplified case it will just use a single string literal, but if he had variables... updated answer to make this clear.

Comment: @ Mark . So in both options no memory will be allocated for temporary string literals "a","b","c". Right?

Comment: @MSach With a StringBuffer, you create 3 string literals ("a", "b", "c") and a StringBuffer. With the first option, you only create one string literal: "abc"

Comment: @mark i am almost close. Now if i do String test1="a"+"b"+args[0]; where arg[0] is determined at run time. How many total object will be created in memory? As per my understanding one. becoz what ever the value of args[0] will be appended in the last of "ab". Will only one object be created. RIGHT?

Answer (score 5):

First of all - use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, `StringBuffer` is deprecated now.

And for your question, nowadays it doesn't really matter, compiler automacally transforms String concacenation to StringBuilder.

There are only two cases where to use it. First one is better code readability (for example if you are building long Strings like SQL queries). And second one, when you concanete Strings in the loop, compiler for always make a new StringBuilder instance for each walk through loop, so be carefull about that.

Comment: +1 While `StringBuffer` is not deprecated, it probably should be as there is almost never a good reason to use it except for legacy libraries which need it. e.g. it is used in SimpleDateFormat, a class which is not thread safe. ;)

Comment: *"compiler automacally transforms String concacenation to StringBuilder"* except for string literals, which the case here.

Comment: Ok, sorry for misinterpretation :)

Comment: @assylias really?I thought that everything which is concacenated is transformed to StringBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `StringBuilder` is to `StringBuffer` what `ArrayList` is to `Vector`: it should be preferred because it's not synchronized.

Your first String is entirely constructed at compilation time, and is stored as a String literal. This literal is interned inside a pool, and the `test` variable always points to the same String instance.

Your second snippet dynamically concatenates, at runtime, three String literals. It returns a new String instance each time it's called.

Comment: I have two questions on this. If i make test=null will literal still reside in pool? Secondly you said "Your second snippet dynamically concatenates, at runtime, three String literals" but as per the link i mentioned it wont allocated any memory for tmporary string literal.This will be inserted in the last. Right?

Comment: test = null just affects null to the variable. The string literal is unchanged. And it stays in the pool, yes. It will allocate memory for the StringBuilder and its internal fields, and for the new String instance created. The three literals are in the pool, and no additional memory is needed for them.

Comment: The order does not matter. You have 4 literals in the pool: "abc", "a", "b", and "c". And the second snippet creates a StringBuffer + an additional String instance each time it's executed.

Comment: i have posted a separate question for this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673596/how-many-objects-will-be-created-during-this-string-operation

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the bytecode generated by the 2 examples, the first string is transformed into the "abc" string literal, whereas the second calls StringBuilder methods. You can actually test it with `System.out.println(test == "abc");`, which prints true.

```
   0: ldc           #2                  // String abc
   2: astore_1      
   3: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuffer
   6: dup           
   7: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuffer."<init>":()V
  10: ldc           #5                  // String a
  12: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
  15: ldc           #7                  // String b
  17: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
  20: ldc           #8                  // String c
  22: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
  25: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuffer.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  28: astore_2
```

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, where you're concatenating three string literals at compile time, the compiler will generate code just as if you'd typed:

```
String test="abc";
```

thus avoiding any intermediate objects altogether.

Comment: so graham in both the cases no intermediate objects will be created right?

Comment: Right, both `"a"+"b"+"c"` and `"abc"` are identical and produce no intermediate objects.

Comment: Sorry graham  i was not able to communicate to you.i  was asking basically, will there be no intermediate objects also in second option in my post which is StringBuffer x = new StringBuffer().append("a").append("b").append("c").toString()?

Answer (score 0):

I think in case of memory usages both are same.